# Get x and y co-ordinate of image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am trying to get x and y co-ordinate on mouse move event of image

Now there are 2 scenarios which i think is utmost important for getting exact co-ordinates

> Note : also i need to put zoomer on image hover
>
> If you want to apply zoomer then image must be displayed in less
>   height and width div than original width and height

In first scenario, i will display the image as it is without any height and width limitations

But in this scenario i won't be able to apply zoomer as per mentioned in above note

Suppose i have image of pixel 2000x1500 then below code works very smoothly

```
var mouseMove = function(e) {
    var X = Math.round((e.pageX - img.offset().left);
    var Y = Math.round((e.pageY - img.offset().top));
};
```

In second scenario, i will display image in fix width and height div which will be smaller than image width and height

Suppose div width and height is 850x750 and you are displaying image of dimension 2000x1500 in that div

Now to get exact x and y co-ordinate code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#competition').on('load', function(e) {
        naturalWidth = e.target.naturalWidth;
    });
});

var mouseMove = function(e) {
    var img = $('#competition');    // div in which image is loaded

    // naturalWidth is origional width of image
    // img.width() is width of div

    ratio = (naturalWidth / img.width());
    var X = Math.round((e.pageX - img.offset().left) * ratio);
    var Y = Math.round((e.pageY - img.offset().top) * ratio);
};
```

Now what happens in second scenario is, when i move mouse horizontally, it gives 3 pixel difference after each mouse move event for x co-ordinate like 1 4 7 10 13

But i want to catch every single pixel of image

Any help would be greatly accepted...

Comment: Well, if you round 2000 / 850 you get exactly 3, thats why you get a "coordinate step" of 3. Can you provide a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: no, it will give output 2.352941 something like this and also i'm not rounding up as i want to catch single pixel from image for which rounding up won't work....anyway i will make jsfiddle for problem and will update you accordingly

Comment: @FreemanLambda check my fiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/rborole06/37q01dpy/7/